# git config global file - remove settings

Tags: git

The following command:

```
$git config --global --list
```

gives me:

```
user.name=test user
user.name=gotqn
```

I want to remove the first name. I referred to this [article](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.5.1/git-config.txt) and have done the following commands but without any result:

```
git config --global --remove-section user.name='test user'
git config --global --remove-section user.name="test user"
git config --global --remove-section user.name=test user
git config --global --remove-section user.name
git config --global --remove-section test user
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and

```
git version
```

gives me

```
git version 1.7.9.5
```

Please, help on this, because I want to try to save my project using git, but do not want to exec the command with 'test user' name.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can edit the `~/.gitconfig` file in your home folder. This is where all `--global` settings are saved.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but is there a way to edit it using commands too?

Comment: @gotqn you can use cat or gedit to edit that.

Comment: @gotqn `gedit ~/.gitconfig` OR `nano ~/.gitconfig`

Comment: @Giri or you could use `vim`... or `ex` or `ed` or `butterflies that focus the cosmic energy in the upper atmosphere that then flip the correct bits in your drive platter`.

Answer (score 104):

Super late answer, but hopefully still helpful:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

Then you're free to:

```
git config --global --add user.name <whatever>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Since the configuration is already made via command line, I think the reverse operation should be done via command line. Otherwise do all configuration in the config file.

Comment: This also works in the scenario you set a `user.name` in a local repo instead of global. Just remove the `--global` flag from both commands.

Comment: You can also remove the email by executing `git config --global --unset-all user.email` if you need to.

Answer (score 10):

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

Or you can just change the user name like this:

```
git config --global --replace-all user.name "New User Name"
```

Comment: This answer was essentially already provided in the question by [user25327](http://askubuntu.com/users/150154/user25327). I think the addition of the `--replace-all` option should be a comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
git config --global -e
```

This command will open GNU nano editor with what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Last but not least usefull, although it's a marginal case is to use

```
git config --global --remove-section user
```

In my case it cleared the data perfectly and with little to no effort

Answer (score 1):

```
git config user.name 'your user name'
git config user.email 'your email name'
```

you can config for your every company project。And global's user name set your private github name and email.I thought this should be the best way for handle this condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `.git/config` file present in the local repository `repo` manually as below:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[user]
        email = <username>@gmail.com
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[credential]
        username = <user_name>
[credential "user"]
        email = <username>@gmail.com
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
"config" 19L, 427C
```

Now try in terminal:

`git push -origin master`

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble trying to clear out double entries for core.editor... I'd run

`git config --unset-all core.editor`

then

`git config --list`

and see no changes.

The answer was to run:

`git config --global --unset-all core.editor`